# XML Serialize elements inside one another

Tags: c#, .net, xml, generics, serialization

I have a class that could be serialized on its own, for example:

```
[XmlRoot("NameOfMyRoot", Namespace = "myNamespace")]
public class Inner
{
    public Inner(){}
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

Which is perfectly serializing into (I am using `ns` alias for `myNamespace`, see full demo)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<NameOfMyRoot xmlns:ns="myNamespace">
    <ns:SomeString></ns:SomeString>
</NameOfMyRoot>
```

Now I want this object to be part of another one (the wrapper):

```
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class Outer<T>
{
    public T Property{ get; set; }

    public Outer(){}
    public Outer(T inner)
    {
        Property = inner;
    }
}
```

Which gives me this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root xmlns:ns="myNamespace">
    <Property>
        <ns:SomeString></ns:SomeString>
    </Property>
</Root>
```

What I want is just embedding inner object as-is into its parent, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root>
    <NameOfMyRoot xmlns:ns="myNamespace">
        <ns:SomeString></ns:SomeString>
    </NameOfMyRoot>
</Root>
```

Notice that namespace should not move to root, and I can't specify element's name, since there will be many different types. 
[Fiddle with full example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CKlnKp).

Of cource, I can just serialize them separately and combine through some nasty string manipulation, but I hope there is a neat way to achieve this somehow.

Comment: Note: the question looks inconsistent; the xml for `[XmlRoot("NameOfMyRoot", Namespace = "myNamespace")] public class Inner {...}` is **not** `<NameOfMyRoot xmlns:ns="myNamespace">` - but rather is `<NameOfMyRoot xmlns="myNamespace">` - that's a huge difference

Comment: @MarcGravell Agreed. Added note on this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no *easy* way to do that. You can do it at runtime, though:

```
// perhaps discover these details at runtime
var attribs = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
attribs.Add(typeof(Outer<Inner>), "Property", new XmlAttributes
{
    XmlElements = { new XmlElementAttribute {ElementName = "NameOfMyRoot" } }
});
attribs.Add(typeof(Inner), "SomeString", new XmlAttributes
{
    XmlElements = { new XmlElementAttribute {  Namespace = "myNamespace"} }
});

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Outer<Inner>), attribs);

var obj = new Outer<Inner> { Property = new Inner { SomeString = "abc" } };
ser.Serialize(Console.Out, obj);
```

Note that you **must** store and re-use such a serializer; for simple `new XmlSerializer()` examples, the serializer is cached internally and re-used; however, for non-trivial cases like this, a new dynamic type is emitted *each time*, so you will leak memory (it won't be unloaded).

That gives you:

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <NameOfMyRoot>
    <SomeString xmlns="myNamespace">abc</SomeString>
  </NameOfMyRoot>
</Root>
```

If you don't want the two `xmlns` alias declaration, those can be removed separately, but they **do not** change the meaning, at least to a compliant reader. Likewise, the `ns` can be added as an alias:

```
var obj = new Outer<Inner> { Property = new Inner { SomeString = "abc" } };
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");
ns.Add("ns", "myNamespace");
ser.Serialize(Console.Out, obj, ns);
```

which gives:

```
<Root xmlns:ns="myNamespace">
  <NameOfMyRoot>
    <ns:SomeString>abc</ns:SomeString>
  </NameOfMyRoot>
</Root>
```

---

As an alternative approach:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot("NameOfMyRoot")]
public class Inner
{
    public Inner() { }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "myNamespace")]
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument(false);
            writer.WriteStartElement("Root");

            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Inner));
            var obj = new Inner { SomeString = "abc" };

            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");
            ns.Add("ns", "myNamespace");
            ser.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
    }
}
```

What I've done here is to manually write the root node, and only get the `XmlSerializer` to write the inner content. Note that I had to change the attributes aroung `SomeString` to make it work in the way you expect (where it is the string that has the namespace, not the object).

Comment: I need namespace to be set on Inner class itself (like it's in class' declaration). Neither on `SomeString`, nor on `Root`. As for element's name substitute it's great.

Comment: @MaximGrishin that's a *namespace alias declaration*, not  namespace; it is equally valid at either level - aliases are inherited and do not change the semantic meaning of the declaring element. If you mean that `NameOfMyRoot` should be in the `myNamespace` namespace: that **is not** what your example shows. I'd be happy to adjust my code to suit - I wrote the code to suit your example.

Comment: @MaximGrishin to be specific, when you say "What I want is just embedding inner object as-is into its parent, like so: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><Root><NameOfMyRoot xmlns:ns="myNamespace">` - in that code `NameOfMyRoot` is in the **empty/default** namespace, not the `myNamespace` namespace.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant that *namespace alias declaration* should belong to `NameOfMyRoot` element.

Comment: @MaximGrishin that isn't directly supported, but the meaning of the data is identical regardless of where the namespace alias declaration resides (or even if it is aliased at all - it could also use explicit namespace syntax). Can I ask *why* you need to move the namespace alias? as it significantly complicates things...

Comment: My serialization works with 3rd party software, which demands such format, regardless of the meaning of the data. They could be manipulating raw strings there for all I know.

Comment: @MaximGrishin k, give me a second; I'll try something else

Comment: Well, now we got really close to what I proposed at the beggining - separate serialization and manual combining. But in that case the wrapper class could get more complicated (obtains more properties) without changing the code. Also, single point of namespace declaration is more clear to read.

Comment: @Maxim yes. If you have unusual requirements, you should expect to have to write unusual code.